# validation on submit button not working

Tags: angularjs

validation on keyup is working but on click of submit button it's not working. When i click on submit it does no validate although redirect to some other page.

```
<script>
            angular.module("MyApp", [])

           .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {


            }]);
        </script>


<div id="loginBox" ng-controller="loginCtrl"> 
<form action="/" id="userLogin" name="myForm" novalidate> 
<label>User id</label> 
<input type="text" ng-model="userId" name="myUserid"  required="" />
    <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted || myForm.myUserid.$touched">
  <div ng-show="myForm.myUserid.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
</div>
     <br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" ng-click="submit()" value="Login" /> 
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to validate. Give some more clear explanation

Comment: i want to validate input text field it ...it is required

Comment: Perhaps `novalidate` attribute of the form should be removed

Comment: @AndreyMischenko nop this attribute only removes the auto validations of the browsers. No connections with angular itself.

Comment: Could you add  the submit function ? Maybe is that what breaking the code.

Comment: And remove the action. As well. Or you can add ng-submit directive and remove ng-click from the submit bottom

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/BchMhCHHETftNuKxBVaj?p=preview      Remove form action   <form id="userLogin" name="myForm" novalidate>

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the **actions** attribute from the form. Like:

```
 <form id="userLogin" name="myForm" novalidate>
```

You can also  add  the directive `ng-submit` in the form and remove the `ng-click` directive  from the submit button.

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro actions was the reason of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ng-app` to your application. I see no error in having `action` in form on anything else. checkin those plnkers

Answer (score 0):

Remove form action .

```
   <form id="userLogin" name="myForm" novalidate>
```

Here is the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/BchMhCHHETftNuKxBVaj?p=preview